# Is it possible to use JCrop to select multiple area in an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a solution where I can mark couple of hotspot area in an image. Found [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php) is very well designed for that. But it allows single area to be highlighted but I want a JavaScript solution where multiple area can be highlighted. Can JCrop do this or are there any other API available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend recommended this API which solves my problem. Want to share the same with you guys.
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1839-jQuery-Photo-Tagger-Plugin-For-Flickr-Style-Photo-Tagging.htm